# Error getting data from subcollection of flutter firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

In a flutter messaging app, chatrooms are created and on the conversation screen, I can access the subcollection of the messages. But when the same subcollection I am trying to access on the main page
(where existing chats are shown) I cannot access them.

I have a collection of ChatRooms, in which users as an array are stored. Then, Messages named subcollection stores the messages.

[image]

See, the document is named lexicographically attached with and in between. Further, it has Messages collection.

[image]

And messages collection is also not empty.

On the main page, the existing chats are shown in listTile. I want to show the last message in its subtitle.

So, here is the last message stateful widget.

```
class _LastMessageState extends State<LastMessage> {
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        future: FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection("ChatRooms")
            .doc(widget.chatRoomID)
            .collection("Messages")
            .orderBy("Time")
        .snapshots()
        .last,
    builder: (context, documentSnapshot) {
      return Text(documentSnapshot.data.docs.last.get("Message"));
    });
  }
}
```

Always the bad state error is coming up.
I would be glad if you could figure out the problem.

Edit : [image]

This is my firestore rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the [`limit()`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/Query/limit.html) method, in order to get a [`QuerySnapshot`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/QuerySnapshot-class.html) **with only one document**. Then you can do as follows, knowing the first (and unique) element of the [`docs`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/QuerySnapshot/docs.html) list is the document you are looking for:

```
return FutureBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
  future: FirebaseFirestore.instance.
        .collection("ChatRooms")
        .doc(widget.chatRoomID)
        .collection("Messages")
        .orderBy("Time", descending: true)
        .limit(1)
        .get(),

  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {

    if (snapshot.hasError) {
      return Text("...");
    }

    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
      if (snapshot.data.size > 0) {
        return Text(snapshot.data.docs[0].get("Message"));
      } else {
        return Text("No document");
      }
    }

    return Text("Loading");
  },
);
```

Comment: It shows, RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0. So, does that mean I cannot access messages collection? I have added cloud firestore rules, would you please take a look.

Comment: Yes, I exactly copied it.

Comment: One more thing, I wanna mention. In the constructor of LastMessage class, I am accepting. chatRoomID.

Comment: and Surprisingly.

Comment: LastMessage( chatRoomID : "DanielandVicky") is working.

Comment: But String chatRoomID = getChatRoomID();  LastMessage(chatRoomID :chatRoomID). Isn't working!!! I have checked getChatRoomID many times, It has no issues. It is just concatinating two usernames lexicographically. Can you suggest anything please? I am left with no idea.

Comment: `RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0`means that the returned `QuerySnapshot`is empty. I've adapted the code to take this case into account. Your security rules allow anyone to read so this is not the reason. Either there is no document or the `CollectionReference` defined by `FirebaseFirestore.instance..collection("ChatRooms").doc(widget.chatRoomID)
.collection("Messages")`is not correct. Probably `widget.chatRoomID`... It's up to you to debug! :-)

Comment: "It is just concatenating two usernames lexicographically." => Are you 100% sure it exactly corresponds to the document ID (casing, etc....)?

Comment: It is working now. Instead of using getChatRoomID, I am manually sorting the names(just first letter). And I don't know why it's working.